# Multiple variables in a single map directive

Tags: nginx

I have the following map based on the value of a cookie:

```
map $cookie_version $version_host {
    default 172.17.0.1:8001;
    2.65.1 172.17.0.1:8001;
    2.65.2 172.17.0.1:8003;
}
```

However I need the same map for the value of a header:

```
map $http_app_version $version_api_host {
    default 172.17.0.1:8001;
    2.65.1 172.17.0.1:8001;
    2.65.2 172.17.0.1:8003;
}
```

Is there a way to not duplicate the map?

My server block:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate         /etc/ssl/nexello.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/nexello.key;
    server_name             _;
    proxy_set_header Host             $host;
    proxy_set_header X-FORWARDED-FOR  $remote_addr;

    charset utf-8;

    location / {
        # Web based access
        # Cookies are used instead of a header because the request passes through here before any javascript can even set a Header.
        if ($cookie_token) {
            proxy_pass https://$version_host;
        }

        # API based access
        # Here we use headers because anyone that is using the API has full control of the headers.
        if ($http_authorization) {
            proxy_pass https://$version_api_host;
        }

        # Auth
        # In case there is no header or cookie we assume that it has no access token and should be redirected to the auth machine.
        proxy_pass https://172.17.0.1:7001;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I somewhat solved this as while there still is two maps, the options are stored in another file so there won't be any reptition:

```
map $cookie_version $version_cookie_host {
    include /etc/nginx/versions.conf;
}

map $http_authorization $version_header_host {
    include /etc/nginx/versions.conf;
}
```

Contents of `/etc/nginx/versions.conf`:

```
default 172.17.0.1:8001;
2.65.1 172.17.0.1:8001;
2.65.2 172.17.0.1:8003;
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
map $cookie_version$http_app_version $version_host {
    default 172.17.0.1:8001;
    # your complicated regex here since two variables will be concatenated.
}
```

and use $version_host in proxy_pass.

Also offtopic, since you're using `if` be careful with it
https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/depth/ifisevil/

Comment: While I know that `if` is evil, I don't see any way to check if a header or cookie is present without using `if`

Comment: Yeah that's true.

Comment: @MathiasHillmann Actually if I look at your usecase, if the values are only going to be `2.65.1/x.x.x` on one of the headers/cookie, setting a map on the concatenated value of `$cookie_version$http_app_version should work`. The regex doesn't need to be that complicated as long as value on them doesn't mismatch (apart from being nil)